# PayPal Payouts REST API - availability?

Tags: rest, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

We implemented the Mass Pay API to do mass payments from our app. When I went to create an NVP/SOAP API app to do this in our Prod environment, the form asked what APIs we planned on using. Sure enough, the Mass Pay API had (deprecated) next to it and told us we should be using the Payouts REST API.

As we were not live yet and still had time before go live, we bit the bullet and rewrote and retested the app to use the Payouts REST API. After creating the REST API app, I noticed Payouts was not 'ticked' for our Live environment, and has a "Contact us" button. So contacted PayPal to enable it, and after 2-3 months and half a dozen calls/emails and being told "it will be enabled in 24-72 hours", decided to contact merchant support.

Merchant support have now told us that the Payouts REST API is only available in the US (we are an Australian company and have an Aus PayPal account).

Yet their documentation clearly says Payouts is available in 150 countries? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/

I really don't know where to go from here - has anyone tried to do this? Any PayPal reps can shed some light on this?

Comment: I've just experienced the same thing with a PayPal UK Business account. Tested everything in sandbox and it worked nicely. Then went to enable in Live environment only to be told to ring customer support. After getting through and being passed around the call centre was told that Mass Payments was an invite only thing and we didn't qualify. They didn't seem too clear about the Payouts API at all but said there was nothing they could do. It is a bit pointless having all the documentation for Payouts API available widely only for it to be available to US Businesses only.

Comment: Refer to my answer below....it works in our live account, it's just unticked in the developer website. Was a painful close to 6 months dealing with PayPal and getting the run around!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for whatever reason we decided to just try using the Payouts API in our live environment and it just worked. It's still unticked in the developer account, but it works in live.

Note: We did have to enable Mass Pay in the account.

I really don't understand, but glad we didn't have to re-write the app again!

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. So you recommend talking to technical support or merchant support to get live approval?